# Cheese showing 'no device found' Thinkpad e450

Tags: usb, lenovo, webcam, thinkpad, cheese

I have recently bought a Lenovo Thinkpad e450 and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Everything works fine but the integrated webcam. Cheese shows `no device found`. Kindly help.

Cheese screenshot:

[image: cheese screenshot]

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:055a Acer, Inc
```

Comment: Can you try with `guvcview` to see  if there is any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your webcam is not support "yet".

But hey! Don't worry, the patch to make it work is now in the -proposed pocket for 16.04 Xenial and 16.10 Yakkety.

When it's verified and confirmed working. It will be promoted to -updates pocket within two weeks from now if everything is fine. And you will be able to fix this issue by updating your system.

Or you can [enable -proposed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) to give it a try, don't forget to provide your feedback on the bug report.

For more information, please refer to this bug report: [Acer, Inc ID 5986:055a is useless after 14.04.2 installed.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hwe-next/+bug/1433906)